# Rename files, moving date part of name from beginning to end

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have filenames that come with the date at the beginning of their names, e.g. `20171015….txt`.

I currently use a batch file to strip off the first 8 characters and this has worked well. However I'd like to now keep the date but move it to the end of the file name.

Comment: Show us the code you are using and accurate examples of your file names that need to be renamed.

Comment: Using a simple regex can be done.

Answer (score 0):

With the file name without extension set as a variable, `%Variable%`:

```bat
Ren "%Variable%.ext" "%Variable:~8%%Variable:~,8%.ext"
```

Or if performed within some sort of loop and delayed expansion enabled, i.e.`SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion`:

```bat
Ren "!Variable!.ext" "!Variable:~8!!Variable:~,8!.ext"
```

Comment: Thank you!  You answered my question... however here's the real question.  Now that I see the answer I realize I left out the whole question.  I have a file like this:  "20171012_title_of_file_1234--KCL.txt.8899"  What I'd REALLY like to do is take the date at the beginning, move it before the ".txt" and remove the everything after the ".txt" so the file name would then look like this: " _title_of_file_1234--KCL.txt"   TIA

Comment: The `.8899` will initially be treated as the extension, so just preprocess the file name removing that extension, then do so again when you `Set Variable`.